# Change Chart Colour Dependant On Cell Value

Tags: excel, vba, colors, cell, shapes

I have a pie chart whose segments I wish to shade dependant on whether the value for an unrelated cell is positive or negative. So if for example cell D4 is positive, then SeriesCollection(1) will be shaded green, and if cell D5 is negative, then SeriesCollection(2) will be shaded red.

I have only been able to to change a *cell* colour dependant on another cell, but not how to change a *shape* colour dependant on a cell.

It is possible that this is only possible using VBA, although I can't figure out how to code this. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the most elegant solution, but it seems to work. It fills in anything positive in a green shade and anything negative in a red shade.

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 3").Activate
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Select

If ActiveSheet.Range("D4").Value > 0 Then

With Selection.Format.Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(146, 208, 80)
    .Transparency = 0
    .Solid
End With

End If

If ActiveSheet.Range("D4").Value < 0 Then

With Selection.Format.Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    .Transparency = 0
    .Solid
End With

End If
```